# To add an administrator to Connected Factory solution accelerator

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

First of all I want to pose my question and elaborate further down this post:

How should it be done to add an administrator to Connected Factory solution accelerator?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-connected-factory-features

The resource downloaded from here is used.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-connected-factory

It was possible to develop to a subscription of a target using "build.ps1". But only the account which developed is an administrator, and the way to make the other accounts an administrator isn't understood.
How should it be done to change the setting?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [assign global admin roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal#assign-roles) to another account. (Remember to select "Global administrator" in the Directory roles)
[image]

Then you need to [assign a subscription administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator#assign-a-subscription-administrator) to the account. (Select the **Owner** role)
[image]